# The Application Data Sheet 37 CFR 1.76 form (aia0014.pdf) does not allow me to sign

Tags: patent-applications, forms

I am trying to sign the PDF form aia0014.pdf. It states that signing is enabled but placing saved content is not. I have downloaded both Adobe Reader 11 and Adobe Reader DC, but the sign tools are disabled. The aia0001 form worked fine. How can I sign this form without printing out, signing, and scanning, which I suspect is not acceptable?

[image: Screenshot of the form in Adobe Reader DC]

Answer (score 1):

I use Nitro 5 PDF tool, downloaded free from Majorgeeks.com.
It has a clickable menu that helps you select any area for text or adding images.  That's how I signed these forms for electronic filing.  My first provisional I typed in everything I could, printed the form, signed it, and scanned it for records and to make a copy for mailing.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following instructions ... you may scan, sign, send

[Signature Requirements](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=597defeb321fc5df8be78cf4e053a3f1&node=se37.1.1_14&rgn=div8)

Comment: I do have Acrobat Pro and I have never had a problem opening a PDF but I could not open this document:  http://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/aia0014.pdf

Comment: Don’t you mean print, sign, scan, send?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type in an electronic "signature", which consists of your name between forward slashes, thus:

/John Q. Agent/   or  /Jane Q. Inventor/ or  /James Q. Assignee/

This suffices for pretty much every document required by the USPTO - even an inventor's declaration can be executed this way.  (I would not use it on an assignment, since that may need to pass muster in a state court.)
Fakery by an applicant or representative would be all too easy, but it's inequitable conduct that risks the validity of the patent (and the career of the representative.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Thanks for the answer to an old question!